# Getting sql server response in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm making a data input page in Asp.net. Entry is fine now and its got all the functionality it needs now but I'd like to have some confirmation that data has been entered.

Initially I had this though using a bit of javascript to show a message box when the query was successful. That worked great until I changed the query insert only when the data entered does not exist in the database already.

Here's the Asp method for data entry:

```
    private void ExecuteInsert(string name, string type)
{
    //Creates a new connection using the HWM string
    using (SqlConnection HWM = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringHWM()))
    {
        //Creates a sql string with parameters
        string sql = " IF NOT EXISTS "
                 + " ( SELECT  1 "
                 + " FROM tblSoftwareTitles "
                 + " WHERE Softwarename = @SoftwareName "
                 + " AND SoftwareSystemType = @Softwaretype "
                 + " ) "
                 + " BEGIN "
                 + " INSERT tblSoftwareTitles (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) "
                 + " VALUES (@SoftwareName, @SoftwareType) "
                 + " END; ";

        //Opns the connection
        HWM.Open();
        try
        {
            //Creates a Sql command
            using (SqlCommand addSoftware = new SqlCommand{
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                Connection = HWM,
                CommandTimeout = 300,
                CommandText = sql})
            {
                //adds parameters to the Sql command
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = name;
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = type;
                //Executes the Sql
                addSoftware.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

and the javascript call

```
 Alert.Show("Software instance saved!");
```

this just goes to a separate file.

Initially I had the message box script occur just at the end of the try statement. I need help in getting a repose from the server that will allow me to display a message box for when there data is fully unique and has saved or for when it isn't unique and hasn't been entered.

I essentially need an if statement that says if the server add a record then show the message box for saved else show the message box saying the data already exists.

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did some research and at first chase up the possibilty of using `executeScalar();` as I can return a value where I thought `executeNonQuery();` didn't return any at all. Seems I was mistaken and it actually returns the number of rows affected. Once I found this out It was a simple case of modifying my code to do what I needed. Here's working code!

```
    private void ExecuteInsert(string name, string type)
{
    int rows = 0;
    //Creates a new connection using the HWM string
    using (SqlConnection HWM = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringHWM()))
    {
        //Creates a sql string with parameters
        string sql = " IF NOT EXISTS "
                 + " ( SELECT  1 "
                 + " FROM tblSoftwareTitles "
                 + " WHERE Softwarename = @SoftwareName "
                 + " AND SoftwareSystemType = @Softwaretype "
                 + " ) "
                 + " BEGIN "
                 + " INSERT tblSoftwareTitles (SoftwareName, SoftwareSystemType) "
                 + " VALUES (@SoftwareName, @SoftwareType); "
                 + " END ; ";

        //Opns the connection
        HWM.Open();
        try
        {
            //Creates a Sql command
            using (SqlCommand addSoftware = new SqlCommand{
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                Connection = HWM,
                CommandTimeout = 300,
                CommandText = sql})
            {
                //adds parameters to the Sql command
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = name;
                addSoftware.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = type;
                //Executes the Sql

                try
                {
                    rows = addSoftware.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (rows >= 1)
                    {
                        Alert.Show("Software Saved");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Alert.Show("Software already exists");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Alert.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

And there you have it! If the combination of software type and software name are already in the database a message box will appear telling the user of that fact. If the Combination of name and type aren't present then the information will be saved and a message box will be displayed telling the user of the successful insert.